# как вытянуть данные из инпута в переменную js

Tags: javascript, html

как сделать так что бы в поле вводился город, по нажатию кнопки данные из поля сохранялись в переменную и с помощью интерпритации работало апи, у меня получилось так, ошибка именно в структуре, по частям код работает, я не знаю как это правильно поставить: \

html

```
<div class="search">
  <button id="submit-btt"><img onclick="getApi(data)" src="./icons/search 1.svg" alt="error"></button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for your preffered city..." class="city_line" name="search" id="city_line">
</div>
```

js

```
let a = document.getElementById("city_line").value;
let data = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=8b7cab1863ae4b3d83f185637231109&q=${a}&days=2&aqi=no&alerts=no`;

async function getApi(api) {
    
    const response = await fetch(api);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Итак.

Ошибка #1 - вы передаёте в вызове getApi переменную api, а откуда её браузеру взять, непонятно.

Ошибка #2 - вычисление значений переменных a и data вне тела функции. Это не константы, выносить их за рамки функций плохая идея.

html:

```
<div class="search">
    <button id="submit-btt"><img onclick="getApi()" src="./icons/search 1.svg" alt="error"></button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for your preffered city..." class="city_line" name="search" id="city_line">
</div>
```

js:

```
async function getApi() {
    let a = document.getElementById("city_line").value;
    let api = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=8b7cab1863ae4b3d83f185637231109&q=${a}&days=2&aqi=no&alerts=no`;

    const response = await fetch(api);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
};
```

Comment: И да, впредь советую проверять свои вопросы, на наличие API ключей. Ими могут воспользоваться злоумышленники, если это например не безобидный сайт погоды, а какая нибудь платёжка ;)

Comment: у input, как ни странно, id задан и он правильный...

Comment: А, ок. Это я уже проглядел. Исправил)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `<img onclick="getApi(data)"`  написать `<img onclick="someFunctionName()"`

И потом её описать

```
function someFunctionName() {
    let a = document.getElementById("city_line").value;
    let data = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=8b7cab1863ae4b3d83f185637231109&q=${a}&days=2&aqi=no&alerts=no`;
    getApi(data);
}

async function getApi(api) {        
    const response = await fetch(api);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
};
```

Comment: имхо, если гетер выполняет только одну функцию,с одними переменными, то писать вызывающую ее функцию нет смысла. Одна задача - одна реализация. Переменные в ней же...

Comment: @YevheniiChukavov в геттер могут поступить данные откуда угодно...из формы, из другой функции, из параметров url. Так что геттер должен быть геттером.......... к тому же, он должен выполнять одну и только одну обязанность (считай что это мини SOLID (точнее "S")).  А взятие данных из инпута И обращение к api - это уже явно две обязанности, никак друг с другом не связанные........и если брать первый пункт моего сообщения, то например данные из инпута могут понадобиться ещё где-то.....в итоге это тоже будет невозможно

Comment: @YevheniiChukavov в текущем случае если и улучшать, то url обращения к api надо вписать в функцию `getApi` и передавать туда данные из внешнего источника и будет `getApi(queryParams)`....но сами эти данные должны браться точно вне этой функции

Comment: Cогласен с каждым словом, как разработчик- только за. Но вопрос стоял вполне себе конкретно, и додумывать условия за топикстартера не в моих правилах. Если бы он написал, что это одна из функций, то патерн facade был бы уместен.